# How can use mongoose/express with ringojs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ringojs

I have tried nodejs for a month, but finally, I'm don't like asynchronous-style programming.

I just found [ringojs](http://ringojs.org/) which seems synchronous-style. I wonder if I can use mongoose and [express](http://expressjs.com/) with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Express and Mongoose are fundamentally built around Node and are asynchronous by design.  Ringojs is a different beast than Node.  Use something from Ringo's ecosystem.  Even if you somehow got Express working, it would probably be a ton of trouble to get and keep it working correctly.  If Ringo doesn't have anything in its own ecosystem worth using then it would probably be a good idea to think twice about using it.

Comment: BTW, the "standard" equivalent to Express for Ringo is Stick (http://hns.github.com/stick/)

Comment: I'd add that node is more active than Ringo, so chances that you'll find libraries for all your needs and support are way higher. That's something you should take into account.
About the sync/async problem : javascript is all about async and callbacks. I think you won't avoid this.

Comment: Definitely one of the main non-feature features of Node is its popularity.  The Node community is mind-blowingly active and as long as you don't mind getting cut by living the bleeding edge from time to time, it can be extremely empowering.

Answer (score 1):

Both node.js and ringo.js rely on [Common.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) specifications so there is a good chance of module compliancy, at least the basic ones.

As mongoose rely on native driver, I am not sure how this is handled by Ringo.